# php dropdown population with first option blank

Tags: php, mysql

can someone tell me is there a possibility to add a "blank option" once the dropdown is populated?

```
echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px">';
            while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
                {
                $value = $rec['route'];
                echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
                }
        echo '</select>';
```

Comment: what do you mean by "once the dropdown is populated"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you do it beforehand?

```
echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px">';
echo '<option value=""></option>';
            while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
                {
                $value = $rec['route'];
                echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
                }
        echo '</select>';
```

Or if you really need it after (don't know why), just add a `selected` option to the `<option>`

```
echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px">';
                while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
                    {
                    $value = $rec['route'];
                    echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
                    }
            echo '<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
            echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Ah yea! why couldn't I crack such a simple thing! shame of ma self! lol Thanks Christopher!

Comment: then give me more information! from what you said i could assume anything

Answer (score 3):

After your `while` block, just add an additional `echo`:

```
echo "<option value=\"$value\"></option>";
```

As already mentioned, it's generally best to do this before your while loop, so 
the default is blank. That way you can catch when/if a user forgets to select an 
option.

Answer (score 0):

simple trick, add extra line after the while loop.

```
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
{
   $value = $rec['route'];
   echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}
echo "<option value=\"$value\"></option>";
```